# Roulette game win streak counter

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I would like to ask for your help.

**The task**

There are 50 observations of the 'game of roulette' a subject has played. Given the fact that the data of the wins and losses are already known (I have the time series) and the value of his total capital increases and decreases after every game I want to calculate the number of total win/loss streaks and the length of average win streak (let's say the starting capital is 100 so the time series goes - series = [102,104,106,105,108,109,120,115,116,118,120,122,..].. in this case the first streak would be 3).

I am firmly new to this and created this riddle on my own to challenge my logic thinking but it seems to me that I am totally lost which also frustrates me.

I wanted to revise my knowledge of loops and conditions in this exercise so it should not be consist of anything else.

Could you please just give me an advice on how to do that? I tried to think in this way but it really makes no sense to me in the end..

```
for i in range (0, len(series)-1):
   while series[i] < series[i+1]:        #While the following game brings profit
      counter_win = counter_win + 1      #The counter of good games should increase by 1 
   break
```

Now I can't find a way of how to start over from the beginning of next sequence of numbers.

Thanks everyone because I'm lost now.

Comment: Do you want to increment a counter whenever you detect the end of a streak (`series[i] > series[i+1]`)?

Comment: Furthermore you will need to keep track of the lengths of all streaks and then you can compute the average. Or you could compute the average on the go without storing the lenghts of all streaks

Comment: Also be careful:„ 102,104,106,105,108,109,120,115,116,118,120,122,..].. in this case the first streak would be 3.)“ the first streak  length is actually 2

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following piece of code:

```py
current_streak = 0
streaks = []
for i in range (0, len(series)-1):
   if series[i] < series[i+1]:        
      current_streak += 1
   elif current_streak > 0:     
      streaks.append(current_streak)
      current_streak = 0

# edge case if the game ends with a streak
if current_streak > 0:
    streaks.append(current_streak)


print("{} Steaks with the average length {}".format(len(streaks), sum(streaks)/len(streaks)))
```

To count the number of losses, you could use the same approach

Comment: This works really well that I couldn't even imagine! Would you mind giving me some resources or advice on how to think in coding? Anything that can help because I feel like this would never come to my mind..

Answer (score 1):

The nested loop in your example will count the first win streak of `3`. As a win streak of `3`, then a win streak of `2` then a win streak of `1`. Use this to get a list of the win streaks:

```
input_ = [100,102,104,106,105,108,109,120,115,116,118,120,122]

win_streak = 0
win_streaks = []
for i in range(1, len(input_)):
    if input_[i] > input_[i-1]:
        win_streak += 1
    elif win_streak > 0:
        win_streaks.append(win_streak)
        win_streak = 0
if win_streak > 0:
    win_streaks.append(win_streak)
average = sum(win_streaks) / len(win_streaks)
print(average)
```

Comment: This works so well, thank you! I just don't understand this line, can you please explain it to me what it does since you already have it in the for loop?
 if win_streak > 0:
    win_streaks.append(win_streak)

Comment: `win_streaks` is a list, calling `win_streaks.append()` will add the given parameter to the end of the list. So `win_streaks.append(win_streak)` will append the current value of `win_streak` to the list.

Answer (score 1):

Hire is a pice of code that demonstrates a possible way of solving your problem.
The code is meant to be instructive so is not optimized too allow easier understanding:

```
data = [102,104,106,105,108,109,120,115,116,118,120,122]

# menages control between win and lose streak 
boolean = False

# actualy counts the number of consecutive wins and loses
counter = 0

# Store the lenght of streak 
win = []
lose = []

for i in range(1, len(data)):
    if data[i] > data[i - 1]:
        #If we were losing and we won one time add streak to array if needed and reset  
         #counter
        if boolean is False:
            if counter != 1:
                lose.append(counter)

                counter = 1
           # Change boolean to address win streak
            boolean = True
        else:
            counter += 1
    if data[i] < data[i - 1]:
        # Same as before but with opposite signs 
        if boolean is True:
            if counter != 1:
                win.append(counter)

                counter = 1
            boolean = False
        else:
            counter += 1
average_win=0
average_lose=0
for i in win:
    average_win+=i
for i in lose:
    average_win+=i


print(average_win/len(win))
print(average_lose/len(lose))
```

Comment: I really like the way you wrote this code! It makes sense to me, thank you!! I just want to make sure that I understand.. Your code primarily checks if the capital is higher or lower and depending on which streak we're at - it either increases the sequence or starts over, right? And the if counter != 1 is the transition from one status to another.

Comment: Counter !=1 checks in the transition if there was actually any streak running when a change in tendency is detected

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it. It's not beautiful but it gets the job done. :)

Given more time I would split this in to separate functions etc.

```
series = [102,104,106,105,108,109,120,115,116,118,120,122]

runs = {}
streak, last = 0, 0 # streak is key variable here as it goes negative for loss-streak
o = 1 # run-counter for our dictionary
for i in series:
    if i > last and last: # first entry isn't a win right?
        # Win
        if streak < 0: # Winds have changed. Reset streak.
            streak = 0
            o += 1
        if o in runs: runs[o] += "w"
        else: runs[o] = "w"
        streak += 1
    elif i < last and last:
        # Loss
        if streak > 0: # Winds have changed. Reset streak.
            streak = 0
            o += 1
        if o in runs: runs[o] += "l"
        else: runs[o] = "l"
        streak -= 1

    last = i

high = sorted([ len(x) for x in runs.values() if "w" in x ],reverse=True)[0]
low = sorted([ len(x) for x in runs.values() if "l" in x ],reverse=True)[0]
print(f"Biggest win spree: {high}, loss spree: {low}")

average_wins = [ len(x) for x in runs.values() if "w" in x ]
print("Average winstreak:",round(sum(average_wins)/len(average_wins),1))
```

Hope this was helpful. Have a good day!

Edit: You don't actually need record_low&high come to think of it. Updated with afew buffs. :)

Comment: First of all thank you for your time! It took me some time to read through it since I am amateur and had to read every line ten times :). Could you please explain what means the "and last" condition in the first if statement? I can't really see. Thanks!!!

Comment: @Martin when the for-loop is entered for the first time `last` has yet to get a proper value; it still has 0 from when we set it up, so therefore it is false; it is just to skip first entry (don't think this is a win anyway?), on next iteration it will have the last value and be true... if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0):

A functional programming solution:

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = [100,102,104,106,105,108,109,120,115,116,118,120,122]

streaks = list(filter(lambda x: x != 0,
                   map(lambda x: sum(x[1]),
                       groupby(map(lambda x,y : x < y, inp, inp[1:])))))

print(streaks, sum(streaks)/len(streaks))
```